# GKE On-prem Support for Openstack

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openstack, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-computing

Is is possible to install GKE-On Prem on Openstack private cloud? I tried to explore various documents, I am not able to be sure other Vmware VSphere, other private cloud set ups are supported or not.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the official [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/overview):

> GKE on-prem runs in your data center in a [vSphere 6.5 or 6.7 Update
> 3](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere.html) environment. vSphere
> is VMware's [server
> virtualization](https://www.vmware.com/topics/glossary/content/server-virtualization)
> software. GKE on-prem uses VMware's [vCenter
> Server](https://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-server.html) to manage
> your clusters.

It may change in future but for now as the documentation says **only VMware vSphere is supported**. See also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/98esww/gke_onprem_surprising_and_a_game_changer_watch/) discussion on **Reddit**.